# Suddenly i am not getting logs on firebase console functions log

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Suddenly my cloud functions are not giving out any logs on firebase console.

I have tried to delete all functions and upload them again

Comment: Your cloud function is using firebase, if using share your code

Comment: the logs are starting to show up but late. like 2hours delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the following incident was affecting.

https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/google-stackdriver/19003

> Google Stackdriver Incident #19003
>   We experiencing delays in showing logging.
>
> Incident began at 2019-04-19 00:11 and ended at 2019-04-19 01:38 (all times are US/Pacific).

Check your project.

https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/usage